# How do i read a typescript file (CSV) in typescript?

Tags: typescript, csv

I don't want to use Javascript but i can't get my code to work.

this is my html:

```
<input #inputUser type="file" (change)="onFileSelect($event.target)" name="myfile" accept=".csv" data-max-size="2048">
```

and this is my typescript:

```
public csvNewContent: string;

onFileLoad(fileLoadedEvent) {
  let csvContent = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
  let re = /;/gi;
  this.csvNewContent = csvContent.toString().replace(re,",");
  console.log(this.csvNewContent);
} // This log prints the right value's


onFileSelect(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  const files = input.files;
  if (files && files.length) {

    console.log("Filename: " + files[0].name);
    console.log("Type: " + files[0].type);
    console.log("Size: " + files[0].size + " bytes");

    const fileToRead = files[0];
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = this.onFileLoad;
    console.log(this.onFileLoad);
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToRead, "UTF-8");
  }
}
```

The OnfileLoad method fills my global variable **csvNewContent** with the csv content stringyfied. When the method is done, it resets this variable to an empty string. I have no I idea why it behaves like this.

Comment: No, the variable csvContent is only used within that specific method, however csvnewContent gets filled outside the scope. However when the method is done, it resets itself to an empty string again. Ive got no clue why it does that.

Comment: Is `public csvNewContent: string;` and these methods in a class?

Comment: Seems that the code that empty your `csvNewContent` is not in what you've posted. Check that you don't recreate the component that own that variable. And post a more complete code, like some other part where you use this `csvNewContent` variable

Comment: This is the only code i am using, yes it is in a class